# How can I "dynamically" pass a veux getter as a prop to my child component?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, getter, vue-props

I am trying to dynamically pass an array into my component's prop. The issue is that this array is fetched by a getter. The reason is that I have multiple lists being fetched from the store and would like to pass them down using a loop.

`Parent.vue` (see line: 2)

```html
<v-tab-item v-for="item in tabItems" :key="item.list">
  <searchCard :items="item.list">
    <template v-slot:content="prop">
      <v-card-title class="text-capitalize">{{ prop.item.name }}</v-card-title>
      <v-card-text>
        <p>Rate:&nbsp;{{ prop.item.rate }}/{{ prop.item.unit }}</p>
        <p>Quantity:&nbsp;{{ prop.item.quantity }}</p>
      </v-card-text>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <plusMinusGroup>
          <p slot="value">{{ prop.item.quantity || 0 }}</p>
        </plusMinusGroup>
      </v-card-actions>
    </template>
  </searchCard>
</v-tab-item>
```

This is what my `tabItems` array looks like and the mapped getters

```js
tabItems: [
  { list: 'prodList', cardHeight: 20 },
  { list: 'materialList', cardHeight: 20 },
  { list: 'itemList', cardHeight: 20 },
],

...mapGetters({
  prodList: 'products/productList',
  materialList: 'materials/materialList',
  itemList: 'items/itemList',
}),
```

The issue is that the value is being intercepted as a String literal (which makes sense) and I can't get it to work.

I have tried substituting `{ list: "prodList", cardHeight: 20 },` with `{ list: this.prodList, cardHeight: 20 },` but that doesn't help.

Also, because my Vuex is split into various modules, I cant use the string provided to fetch the getter inside the child module.

Comment: Is `tabItems` computed property? Or data property? Do you have such getters in your store? Can you provide you store code?

Comment: maybe you can use `$store.getters[item.list]` somehow instead of doing that. Have not used Vue for a year so cant say

Comment: @Javas As you can see, tabItems is the array over which the v-for runs.
The getters in my code are displayed underneath
my store code is too big to fit here, and I am not very sure which parts would be relevant to this question, what is required is that the getter returns an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difficulty here is that there isn't a `$computed` equivalent to `$data`. If there were this would be easy.

One option is to put an explicit `this` in the template:

```html
<searchCard :items="this[item.list]">
```

If you're running a linter it'll probably complain about that though.

The instance does have a reference to itself in the `_self` property. The underscore indicates that it's private so we shouldn't really be using it. In theory you could create your own alias:

```js
data () {
  return {
    self: this
  }
}
```

then:

```html
<searchCard :items="self[item.list]">
```

Seems a bit hacky though.

There are tricks using property getters that would work but I think that would just complicate things. e.g. Putting a getter on each tab item that proxies through to the relevant list.

The simplest way would probably be to provide a method:

```js
methods: {
  getList (listName) {
    return this[listName]
  }
}
```

with:

```html
<searchCard :items="getList(item.list)">
```

To me that seems the least likely to cause confusion to future maintainers of the code.

Comment: I think I will go with option 2 as it makes a lot of sense and is cleaner.